# How to handle Access "Run-Time Error 3021 - No current record" after DoCmd.Requery?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, runtime-error

I have been having a quite annoying issue on my access project.
It is an Access 2007 - 2016 file.

My database has two queries that I intend to use to filter data to feed combo-boxes.
On one of my forms I have done that with success. The first list is fed from a table, and the succeeding ones are fed by filtering their respective table based on the previous list selection.
[Here is a screenshot of my form that worked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs5QM.png).
And here is part of the code that goes with it:

```
Private Sub frm01ListSetor_Click()

DoCmd.Requery (qry01_frm01ListArea)
Me![frm01ListArea] = Null

DoCmd.Requery (qry02_frm01ListEquip)
Me![frm01ListEquip] = Null

Me![frm01TextID] = Null

End Sub

Private Sub frm01ListArea_Click()

DoCmd.Requery (qry02_frm01ListEquip)
Me![frm01ListEquip] = Null

Me![frm01TextID] = Null

End Sub
```

Here are the queries that goes along with the code above:

- qry01_frm01ListArea

```
SELECT tblAreas.ID_Area, tblAreas.NomeArea
FROM tblAreas
WHERE (((tblAreas.SetorArea)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListSetor]));
```

- qry02_frm01ListEquip

```
SELECT tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento, tblEquipamentos.NomeEquipamento
FROM tblEquipamentos
WHERE (((tblEquipamentos.SetorEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListSetor]) AND ((tblEquipamentos.AreaEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListArea]))
ORDER BY tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento;
```

The code above works just fine. It filters data to previous selection accordingly and it also clears the data and selection of the "righter" lists every time another value is selected on the "lefter" ones.
So that was a form I created to help me out on populating my equipment database.

Let us get to the problematic twin now:

I created another form for Maintenance Orders of these equipment.
This one must be more user friendly since other people will use it. Therefore I used Combo-boxes for value selection instead of List Boxes. I say this before hand because it is the only thing I could notice that differs the new form from the one above.

Here I have this:
[Screenshot of troubled form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qhr9.png)

After the expanded Combo-box on image 2 is selected I should run the following code:

```
Private Sub frm02SetorOM_Click()

    DoCmd.Requery (qry04_frm02CBArea)
    Me![frm02AreaOM] = Null

    DoCmd.Requery (qry05_frm02CBEquip)
    Me![frm02EquipamentoOM] = Null

End Sub

Private Sub frm02AreaOM_Change()

    DoCmd.Requery (qry05_frm02CBEquip)
    Me![frm02EquipamentoOM] = Null

End Sub
```

It is basically the very same thing I have done on the first form but with different variables.

But I get a "Run-time error 3021: No current record" every time I select a value on my "Setor" field.
The crash happens at the "DoCmd.Requery (qry04_frm02CBArea)" line.

Here is the query for this form's Area field (qry04_frm02CBArea):

```
SELECT tblAreas.ID_Area, tblAreas.NomeArea
FROM tblAreas
WHERE (((tblAreas.SetorArea)=[Forms]![frm02_SubmitOM]![frm02SetorOM]));
```

But the thing that is confusing me the most is that when I click "End" on the Run-time error dialog box, my Area combo-box - that was empty before - even with the error gets the proper options like if it actually "requeried".

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.
Btw, this is my first Access project so please consider that on the response.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)! E.g show code not images! Error most likely caused by combo bound to another column (e.g. when showing RLA, value is a number (id if RLA), not the text (show cömbo sql).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to these instructions. It did help me out indeed. In fact I managed to replace some screenshots by codes for the queries making it much more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Note: the proper command to requery a combobox is `Me.NameOfCombobox.Requery`, though I don't know if that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: If error, form has records (Debug.Print Me.Recordset.RecordCount)? If [Forms]![frm02_SubmitOM]![frm02SetorOM] is bound to ID_Area, tblAreas.SetorArea need to represent the id not the tblAreas.NomeArea text. You can export the form to text, with `Application.SaveAsText acForm, "frm02SetorOM", "Form_frm02SetorOM.txt"`to show us the relevant conf.

Comment: @Andre, that actually solved the problem. Weird thing is that my other form worked out using the DoCmd.requery function but this one didn't. But well.. even though I would like to understand why one works and the other doesn't I might just change my code according to your suggestion and move on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, where would I put the Application.SaveAsText acForm, "frm02SetorOM", "Form_frm02SetorOM.txt  on my code to fetch this text file? That seems to be a good debugging tool.<br/>Also, I added the Debug.Print Me.Recordset.RecordCount at the beginning of the on_change code and it printed 0.

Comment: Doesn't matter where to put, even immediate window works.

Comment: I get Run-time error 32584: No object with the given name and type exists in the current database.

Comment: Btw, if I use Debug.Print Me.frm02SetorOM, I get the ID number for that Setor (Sector in portuguese) and not the Setor name. So I believe it is correct in what comes to that.

Comment: Sorry, should be forms name, not control `Application.SaveAsText acForm, "frm02_SubmitOM", "Form_frm02_SubmitOM.txt"`